# Image map element won't get used

Tags: html, css

My map element won't go on my image element. Thanks in advance!!

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="4" style="width: 209px;" valign="middle" align="center">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sEwFehp.png" style="width: 360px; height: 425px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="veneboer" title="veneboer" href="http://www.veneboercampers.nl/" coords="792,262,585,135" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="dejong" title="dejong" href="http://www.dejonghattem.nl/" coords="598,365,804,452" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="acb" title="acb" href="https://www.acb-caravans.nl/" coords="427,394,595,522" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="caravanextra" title="caravanextra" href="https://www.caravanextra.nl/" coords="424,737,617,819" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="mobiledrome" title="mobiledrome" href="http://www.mobiledrome.nl/" coords="107,684,275,800" shape="rect">
</map>
</td>
```

Comment: Your HTML shows the image in a table and a width/height that does not match any of the coordinates

Comment: I changed the code so that the map element is inside the td element but this still does not work

Comment: You need to fix the width and height. As soon as I remove the widht and height you set for the image using browser dev tools, tabbing through the areas works perfectly fine with the shown snippet.

Comment: @CBroe I found this out as well, I've posted my answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/sEwFehp.png" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="veneboer" title="veneboer" href="http://www.veneboercampers.nl/" coords="792,262,585,135" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="dejong" title="dejong" href="http://www.dejonghattem.nl/" coords="598,365,804,452" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="acb" title="acb" href="https://www.acb-caravans.nl/" coords="427,394,595,522" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="caravanextra" title="caravanextra" href="https://www.caravanextra.nl/" coords="424,737,617,819" shape="rect">
    <area target="_blank" alt="mobiledrome" title="mobiledrome" href="http://www.mobiledrome.nl/" coords="107,684,275,800" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Your table messes up your image map. It works fine without one~

Comment: Your method removes the style and the image needs to be inside a table, I found a working solution and I'll post it down below.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="4" style="width: 209px;" valign="middle" align="center">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fzHXBZw.png" style="width: 360px; height: 425px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;" usemap="#image-map">
    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="_blank" alt="veneboer" title="veneboer" href="https://veneboercampers.nl/verhuur/ " coords="96,7,240,85" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="acb caravans" title="acb caravans" href="https://www.acb-caravans.nl/camper-verhuur/ " coords="73,95,190,194" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="de jong hattem" title="de jong hattem" href="https://www.dejonghattem.nl/campers/verhuur/ " coords="350,126,223,188" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="mobile drôme" title="mobile drôme" href="https://www.mobiledrome.nl/campers/camper-huren/ " coords="5,221,141,307" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="caravan extra" title="caravan extra" href="https://www.caravanextra.nl/kampeerautos/kampeerautoverhuur/ " coords="319,261,181,310" shape="rect">
    </map>
 </td>
```

This works!